# How to delete vertices in graph in R?

Tags: r, social-networking, igraph

I’m trying to remove the vertex in a graph with `delete.vertices(graph ,vertex id)` but I see this error: `”Cannot create iterator, Invalid vertex id, Invalid vertex id”`

This is my code:

```
graph<-read.graph(paste0("H:/graph.txt"),format="ncol",directed="TRUE")
delete.vertices(graph,c(717527,61373))
```

717527 and 61373 are my vertices number.

and this is the graph:

[image: vertices]

How can I do this?

Answer (score 5):

You get the error because one of the vertices given is not in the list of the graph vertices. One advise try to play with `igraph` functions, and once your are familiar with them apply it to your custom graph. Here a demonstration:

```
 library(igraph)
 g <- graph.ring(10)
 V(g)
Vertex sequence:
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

Now I try to delete an existing vertex:

```
delete.vertices(g, c(2,7,9) )
IGRAPH U--- 7 4 -- Ring graph
+ attr: name (g/c), mutual (g/x), circular (g/x)
```

For non existing one , I get your error:

```
delete.vertices(g, c(20))

Error in delete.vertices(g, c(20)) : 
  At iterators.c:759 : Cannot create iterator, invalid vertex id, Invalid vertex id
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Igraph?

the read.graph function may be reading vertex id's in as strings. In that case you may want:

```
delete.vertices(graph,c('717527','61373'))
```

instead. Also, delete.verticies returns a new graph object. You want to make sure to store the result in your graph if you want to see the changes show up latter.

```
graph<-read.graph(paste0("H:/graph.txt"),format="ncol",directed="TRUE")
graph<-delete.vertices(graph,c('717527','61373'))
```